# What cards from MTG: Origins are not in Magic Duels?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, magic-duels

Magic Duels features most cards from the latest MTG edition, but some are missing. What are those missing cards ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cards that are in MTG: Origins and are not in Duels are the following, sorted by color:

**White:**

- Aven Battle Priest
- Charging Griffin
- Enlightened Ascetic
- Enshrouding Mist
- Gideon's Phalanx
- Hallowed Moonlight
- Healing Hands
- Heavy Infantry
- Mighty Leap
- Murder Investigation
- Sentinel of the Eternal Watch
- Starfield of Nyx
- Swift Reckoning
- War Oracle
- Yoked Ox

**Blue:**

- Clash of Wills
- Day's Undoing
- Deep-Sea Terror
- Dreadwaters
- Jace's Sanctum
- Maritime Guard
- Mizzium Meddler
- Negate
- Nivix Barrier
- Psychic Rebuttal
- Send to Sleep
- Skaab Goliath
- Stratus Walk
- Turn to Frog
- Watercourser

**Black:**

- Catacomb Slug
- Dark Dabbling
- Dark Petition
- Demonic Pact
- Eyeblight Massacre
- Fetid Imp
- Gnarloot Trapper
- Infinite Obliteration
- Macabre Waltz
- Nightsnare
- Returned Centaur
- Revenant
- Tormented Thoughts
- Touch of Moonglove
- Weight of the Underworld

**Red:**

- Acolyte of the Inferno
- Boggart Brute
- Chandra's Fury
- Cobble Brute
- Demolish
- Goblin Piledriver
- Lightning Javelin
- Magmatic Insight
- Prickleboar
- Seismic Elemental
- Skyraker Giant
- Smash to Smithereens
- Volcanic Rambler

**Green:**

- Aerial Volley
- Caustic Caterpillar
- The Great Aurora
- Hitchclaw Recluse
- Honored Hierarch
- Joraga Invocation
- Leaf Gilder
- Managorger Hydra
- Mantle of Webs
- Reclaim
- Skysnare Spider
- Somberwald Alpha
- Sylvan Messenger
- Vastwood Gorger
- Vine Snare

**Artifacts:**

- Alhammarret's Archive
- Angel's Tomb
- Brawler's Plate
- Gold-Forged Sentinel
- Guardians of Meletis
- Hangarback Walker
- Helm of the Gods
- Jayemdae Tome
- Mage-Ring Responder
- Orbs of Warding
- Prism Ring
- Pyromancer's Goggles
- Ramroller
- Sword of the Animist
- War Horn

**Lands:**

- Battlefield Forge
- Caves of Koilos
- Llanowar Wastes
- Mage-Ring Network
- Shivan Reef
- Yavimaya Coast

Comment: Abbot of Keral Keep is in Duels.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Indeed I remember this one, thanks.